# Excel columns to multiple rows

Tags: excel, rows, transpose, normalize

I have a set of data that consists of a product SKU, and then the sizes as multiple columns. I need to transpose this data to list the sizes in one column (which I can do) but, each size needs to list the SKU as well which is something I can't seem to achieve with transpose. See images for an example.

[image: What I am after]

Comment: It is expected that you show some effort before asking for solutions.

Comment: Just because I didn't write an essay about all the hours I spent trying to do it myself and failing doesn't mean I didn't try at all

Comment: Hi - in that case in the future post a sample of what you have tried. You will get more assistance if you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps...

## 1

Click on a cell to the right of your data.

On the keyboard press Alt and then while holding Alt down, press D and let go.

Now press P on the keyboard.

The ancient PivotTable Wizard should now be displayed.

## 2

Select `Multiple Consolidation Ranges`. Click on the Next button.

## 3

Select `I will create the page fields`. Click on the Next button.

## 4

For the Range field at the top of the dialog, select the range A1:J6. (This is your sample data.)  Click on the FINISH button.

## 5

You will now see a PivotTable. You are going to double-click one particular cell... and this will create a new worksheet with your data transposed and normalized. That cell is the bottom-right cell of the PivotTable (at the intersection of Grand Total and Grand Total). Double-click it.

## 6

On the new sheet that is now displayed, delete column B and click on the little arrow in cell B1. Uncheck (Blanks) and click OK.

That's it. It seems like a lot, but it's not. It takes just a couple of seconds once you get used to it. And you can go ahead and delete the PivotTable now. And you can copy your normalized data out of the filtered rows and paste wherever you like... and then just delete that temporary sheet.

Comment: To whomever down voted this 2 months after it was accepted by the OP as solving their problem, thanks... your a peach.